# can you recommend an opencv plot library

Tags: opencv

After performing DFT in openCV 2.4.10 I wish to plot the matrix I got,
these are complex numbers,
I have looked into https://code.google.com/p/cvplot/
however I can see the it is only supported up to openCV 2.3. 
Is there a better way to do plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenCV isn't really intended for this kind of application. I would suggest using some other plotting-oriented library, or simply exporting the data to an external dedicated plotting software (i.e. Matlab). There is also a number of C++ graphing widgets for the Qt library:

- http://www.qcustomplot.com/
- http://qwt.sourceforge.net/